# CUDA предельное кол-во обрабатываемых массивов одним kernel'ом

Tags: c++, c, cuda

Может вопрос глуповат, но все таки задам его. Опишу ситуацию, есть десять векторов одинакового размера, пускай первый вектор заполнен случайными числами, остальные вектора просто объявлены, выделяем память на "устройстве" для каждого из этих массиво, естественно соблюдая соответствие в размерах векторов и выделяемой области памяти на "устройстве", далее копируем первый вектор на "устройство", после чего запускаем "kernel" в нем идет простое прибавление единицы к каждому элементу вектора, с последующей записью результата сложения в следующий вектор и так 10 раз, после чего копируем результат последнего вектора с "устройства" на "хост" и последующего поочередного вывода элементов вектора в консоль, и все казалось бы просто и примитивно, но возникает непонятная проблема, к примеру результат пятого вектора выводится, а элементы последующих векторов обращаются в нули. Буду крайне благодарен если кто то тыкнет меня носом в ошибку.

Comment: А у вас ядро при этом сколько выполняется? Оно по таймауту не отваливается ли?

Comment: Нет не отваливается, весь расчет длится около 1мс.